# Find and replace at powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

My textfile looks like this:

```
-------------------
Set PRGVER="V1.0.12"
Set PRGDIR=C:\PRGSTD\oif_mes\OIFplus
Set PRGEXE=OIFplus.bat
Set PRGTXT=OIFplus

echo %PRGTXT%, %PRGVER%
start "%PRGTXT%" /D%PRGDIR%\%PRGVER%\ %PRGDIR%\%PRGVER%\%PRGEXE%
----------------------
```

What I wan't to do, edit this file, only change `Set PRGVER="V1.0.12"` to a new number,  like this `Set PRGVER=V1.0.13"`.
When is start the PS Script, I don't know the whole string, the number between `""`.
I only know, find string variable: `Set PRGVER=""`.

How can I replace only the first value between `""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this;

```
$srt = <your text>
$r = $str -replace "PRGVER=`".*`"", "PRGVER=`"your_replace`""
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it. It finds the a line that starts with 'Set PRGVER="V', followed by any number of digits, then a dot, any number of digits, a dot, any number of digits, and ends with '"'. When found, the line is replaced with 'Set PRGVER="V1.0.13"' and the result is saved back to the file.

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '^Set PRGVER="V\d+\.\d+.\d+"$','Set PRGVER="V1.0.13"' | Out-File file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Following PoSH will replace `PRGVER` value:

```
$newValue = "v123.456.789"
gc D:\temp\text | % { $_ -ireplace '(Set PRGVER=)\"([^"]*)\"', ('$1"' + $newValue + '"') };
```

Answer (score 0):

You using key: Ctrl + H

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7